# Finally clause alternative for script timeout

Tags: php, cron

I'm training a PHP script to run as a well behaved cron job. To escape infinite loops and such I've added `set_time_limit`.

As far as I know there is not finally clause functionality for PHP. I would like to have such  functionality to cleanup, like unlinking files when the time limit is reached.

What would be an alternative way to accomplish this?

Comment: files will be closed on script terminating in any case.

Comment: OZ_, In this case I need also to unlink files. Updated my question txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruce Aldridge already answered, how it can be reached.
I show you another way: [RAII pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) (not to say that is better or worse)
Example:

```
class AutoUnlinker
{
    private $files;

    public function OpenFile($filepath, $mode)
    {
        $handler = fopen($filepath, $mode);
        $this->files[$filepath] = $handler;
        return $handler;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        if (!empty($this->files))
        {
            foreach ($this->files as $filepath => $handler)
            {
                if (!empty($handler)) fclose($handler);
                if (file_exists($filepath)) unlink($filepath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If this class will be used for opening files, all files will be closed and unlinked on script termination. This example specially for your question - usually 1 object being used to give access to 1 resource.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I need to check that set_time_limit exceptions will call the destructor.

Comment: according to a quick test the __destruct of an object will not be called when the set_time_limit value is exceeded 

`<?php

set_time_limit(1);

class Foobar {
    
    public function doIt() {
        while(true) {
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        echo "destruct called";
    }
}

$foo =new Foobar();
$foo->doIt();`

Comment: @WardB Because set_time_limit not throws exception, but generates Fatal Error. I don't think it's normal style of coding and script execution. Will be better check timer in each iteration. But, if you only want to handle Fatal Error - it's not trivial issue - you can use `ob_start()` function. But don't think that it's my advice - fatal errors can not be part of good algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

actually, this won't run on script timeout.
**and** it would be better to handle catches for infinite loops in the code.