# PHP finally clause

Tags: php, exception

What is the best practice to simulate a finally clause? I realize this could be considered related (though I don't think it's a duplicate) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043768/finally-clause-alternative-for-script-timeout).

However, in my case I want to handle exceptions, I want to use finally (or whatever PHP equivalent or practice) as defined by python:

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not.

Just loosely writing the code after the try-catch block seems like an ugly practice to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [RFC for adding finally to PHP](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/finally), they suggest this workaround:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect();
try {
   call_some_function($db);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   mysqli_close($db);
   throw $e;
}
mysql_close($db);
```

So unless you upgrade to PHP 5.5 (which will contain the `finally` construct), this is probably your best option.

Comment: One could create a lambda that gets called in both the catch block and after the entire try-catch block to avoid repeating code, though this can easily get impractical if the code depends heavily of the variables defined in the scope. Too bad Lambdas in php don't inherit the scope chain like JS does.

Comment: @Mahn PHP doesn't have a scope chain, all variables other than superglobals are scoped to the current function, so having closures work differently would be really weird.

Comment: @Mahn All unqualified variable names, that is. Actually, there is one other exception I just thought of: for some reason `$this` "falls" into the scope of static functions, even outside the current class.

Comment: Last line should be mysqli_close($db); not mysql_close($db); ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This could be considered something of a non-answer, but there are ways of structuring code that mean `finally` is not needed, such as the "RAII Pattern" ("Resource Acquisition Is Initialization") where cleanup of a resource is done in the destructor of a locally scoped variable representing that resource.

The idea is that if an exception rips you out of function scope, your destructor will fire, so your cleanup happens as expected. If no exception is thrown, you will reach the end of your function, and your variable will go out of scope that way.

A quick Google turned up [this simple code for doing it with arbitrary callbacks](http://blog.kentarok.org/entry/2012/09/30/205227).

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.5 and later do have the [finally](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) construct.

From the docs:

```
try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} finally {
    echo "First finally.\n";
}
```

Comment: Or, since it's not technically released yet, PHP 5.5 and later *will* have the `finally` construct ;)

Comment: Not a very helpful answer considering 5.5 is in alpha released 5 days ago.

Comment: Future proofing this question ;)  Thought it had been around for a while considering how long it's been talked about.

Comment: @lafor Actually, the first Alpha was released 4 months ago, but yeah, not final yet.

Comment: @BradKoch It *should* have been released by now, but they decided to hold it up while they integrated Zend Optimiser+ [https://wiki.php.net/rfc/optimizerplus]

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck maintaining pre 5.5 legacy code, and you don't mind the overhead of a mandatory fake throw every call, there is always this dirty little trick.

```
try { 
     // do your worst to mess things up.

     throw new Exception("finally");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //TODO: after upgrading to 5.5, make this a legit try/catch/finally
    if ( ($msg = $e->getMessage())  != "finally"){
        // real catch
        echo "Exception doing something :" . $msg;
    } else {
        // quasi finally.
    };
}
```